# How to remove floating text options whenever I create a text box?

Tags: gimp

[image]

Every time I use Text tool to create a textbox in gimp 2.8, the textbox has an attached translucent options menu that is seriously annoying.

How do I get rid of it?

I'm used to editing text in gimp 2.6 (which works much better in many ways), but I want to avoid downgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Simply select another tool in the tool box, such as the `Move` tool, then it will go away, leaving only the text and layer boundary visible.  The <kbd>M</kbd> key will switch to the Move tool, if you want a shortcut.

If you don't want to see the layer boundary, in the main menu along the top click `View`, and deselect `show layer boundary`

There is no way, as far as I know, to disable the text box options display while using the Text tool.  You can enable the old "Use Editor" option in the tool options for the Text tool, but it still doesn't disable the text box display.

[image: Screenshot of GIMP]

Answer (score 0):

It is infuriatingly difficult to get rid of the text box around the last thing you wrote. No amount of double clicking or switching tools seems to help. Here's what you have to do: Click on the text box with the text box tool or the select tool. Go to Edit>Copy. Then Edit>paste in place.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to layer
2. Select the layer with the text you'd just created.
3. Right click on Merge Down

Answer (score 0):

This bothered me for while too.  You probably just want to press Page-Down, which moves you to a different layer.

Answer (score 0):

Really, none of the answers deal with this annoying problem.  The answers above may as well have been, "Well, close Gimp, and you won't see the floating text box."  The problem is as long as the floating text box is open, it disables the font selection, color selection, and size selections in the tab tools dialogue. You can still change the spacing and box type, but not the font.  That is annoying because there are tools in the tabs version that let you compare fonts... if you want to scroll down a list of fonts to quickly compare fonts as you might in the tab tools you're SOL because of that POS.  What purpose does it serve anyway?!